# Input Initial Value With Onblur/Onfocus Later

Tags: jquery, input, onblur, onfocus

I have written the following code which grabs the title attribute of the input field to use as placeholder text on the input. When focussed this becomes empty so you can type.

If you click off then the text reappears using the onblur - great.

BUT I can't figure out how to initially set the input to contain that title in the first place to then make empty on focus.

```
                var title = $('#keywords').attr('title');

                $("#keywords").focus(function() {
                    this.value = "";
                });

                $("#keywords").blur(function() {
                    this.value = title;
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
$('#keywords').val(function(){
   return this.title; // return the title to be set as value
});
```

And, you can simplify your code to

```
$('#keywords').val(function(){
   return this.title; // return the title to be set as value
}).focus(function(){
   this.value = "";
}).blur(function(){
   this.value = title;
});
```

Comment: That makes the text display initially, but then when you click in and click out the text does not return.